Error with Adw.PreferencesDialog on dialog close
I get this error when I close my Adw.PreferencesDialog:
(multiplicar:2): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 13:17:43.002: Widget of type “Preferencias” already has an accessible role of type “GTK_ACCESSIBLE_ROLE_GENERIC”

If I try to open it again the application crash.
I open the dialog on this code:
    def on_preferences_action(self, _action, _param):
        print(self.preferencias)
        if self.preferencias is None:
            self.preferencias = Preferencias() # Adw.PreferencesDialog
        self.preferencias.present()

The first time I run the action the dialog opens correctly and print(self.preferencias) prints None as espected.
If I close de dialog I get the error:
(multiplicar:2): Gtk-CRITICAL **: 13:17:43.002: Widget of type “Preferencias” already has an accessible role of type “GTK_ACCESSIBLE_ROLE_GENERIC”

If I try to open it again the application crash and print(self.preferencias) prints <preferencias.Preferencias object at 0x7fc85cf66780 (Preferencias at 0x586889a2a3d0)> so I guess that the problem is that the dialog is not destroyed on close.
I have tried self.preferencias.present(self.win) beeing self.win my main Adw.ApplicationWindow but the same happens.
I have tried self.preferencias.get_parent().set_hide_on_close(True). This way the error persits and it works but I thing is not the best parctice.
What I'm doing wrong?
